# How does the flicker fusion threshold prove time perception?

Tags: visible-light, time, biophysics, perception

The flicker fusion threshold allows us to see when an animal can distinguish a flash of light and when they can only see a solid light. They have proven flies can see the light flicker at almost 240hz unlike humans at 60hz. So how does the ability of seeing if the light is flickering tell their perception of time? Couldn't it just tell us if they can see it or not, with no relationship to time?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flicker_fusion_threshold

Comment: Nobody yet knows what brain process is responsible for the psychological perception of time. I personally think is unrelated to the flicker fusion threshold.

Comment: So is there anyway to scientifically measure the perception of time?

Comment: There are many techniques used by psychophysicists, just google it

Comment: Google only states the flicker fusion method

Answer (score 0):

I am also interested in this subject. Not only is the flicker fusion an indication of the relative speed of processes in differing species, but also the metabolic rate, life expectancy, heart beat rate, reaction time……
…all seem to be related to the size of a species.